# Error Handling : Spring Integration

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration

I am completely new to Spring Integration. Following is my requirement :

I have to poll a given location (say a directory in interval of 5 sec.) for a file (with a given pattern - defined by regex.). IF the file is found that I have to perform certain operation(s) on the file (say log a message "File found", save the file to another location, etc.) and if the file is NOT found then the program needs to log a message say - "Polling interval 5 sec ... File not found". The program also needs to poll for 9 hrs. and after that it should STOP polling i.e. program should QUIT.

I would like to take care of various error scenarios such as:

1) Folder not present: What would happen if the folder (directory) which is being polled for the file is not present? My latest code is as follows:

```
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter
channel="contextStartedEventChannelChannel" event-      types="org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent"
payload-expression="new java.io.File('${myapp.incomingFile.path}').exists()" />

<int:router input-channel="contextStartedEventChannelChannel"
    expression="payload">
    <int:mapping value="true" channel="trueChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="false" channel="falseChannel" />
</int:router>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter id="trueChannel"
    expression="@'incomingFiles.adapter'.start()" />

<int:outbound-channel-adapter id="falseChannel"
    ref="errorTracker" method="processError" />
```

Code for Inbound-channel-adapter:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="incomingFiles"
        directory="file:${myapp.incomingFile.path}" prevent-duplicates="true"
        filename-regex="${ETD.filenameRegex}"  auto-create-directory="false"
        auto-startup="false">
```

Issues:

1)  But now what's happening is that when I delete the polled directory purposefully then as expected we are getting an exception but its coming as a stacktrace on the console and its not going on an error channel.

2) Currently we are only taking care of one error scenario i.e. if the polled directory is not present. I would also want to implement other error scenarios such as network down, etc. , etc. and would like to just show a message on the logger (i.e. pass on the error channel) and gracefully exit the program.

Please do kindly suggest what's wrong.

Following is the exception which I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'incomingFiles.adapter': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'incomingFiles.adapter.source' while setting bean
>   property 'source'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'incomingFiles.adapter.source': FactoryBean
>   threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Source directory**
>   [C:\TEMP\incomingFile] **does not exist**.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at com.jefferies.fileutility.App.main(App.java:31) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'incomingFiles.adapter.source': FactoryBean
>   threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source directory
>   [C:\TEMP\incomingFile] does not exist.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
>     ... 15 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Source**
>   **directory [C:\TEMP\incomingFile] does not exist.**  at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)    at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.onInit(FileReadingMessageSource.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.initSource(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.getObject(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.getObject(FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean.java:40)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
>     ... 20 more

Answer (score 0):

Certain errors are considered hard errors (detected during bean initialization) and prevent the context from being initialized. In this case, to prevent this error, you need to set auto-create directory.

The conditions that are required are in `onInit()`...

```
    if (!this.directory.exists() && this.autoCreateDirectory) {
        this.directory.mkdirs();
    }
    Assert.isTrue(this.directory.exists(),
            "Source directory [" + directory + "] does not exist.");
    Assert.isTrue(this.directory.isDirectory(),
            "Source path [" + this.directory + "] does not point to a directory.");
    Assert.isTrue(this.directory.canRead(),
            "Source directory [" + this.directory + "] is not readable.");
```

Other, runtime, errors will indeed go to the poller's configured `error-channel` (or `errorChannel` by default).

Comment: Gary, I am afraid I have not understood your solution. where do I need to write this code? And why my error is not going to error-channel or errorChannel ? Please guide me.

Comment: I have given auto-startup="false" in <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>  then why its looking for the directory and giving an exception.? What's the logic for the same. Its hard to understand.

Comment: As I have shown; the bad directory is not a runtime error, it's an initialization error - the application simply won't start. The code I showed is the code in the framework to show that you need a valid directory (or it needs to be created automatically). Other (runtime) errors will go to the error channel.

Comment: Gary is right: your config looks good. Now you should configure `error-channel` for the `<poller>` of `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` and get deal with exceptions in the subscriber for that channel.

Comment: Artem, I already configured error-channel for the <poller> of <int:file:inbound-channel-adapter> still I am getting exception as a stacktrace. Please do find my complete configuration as per below:     <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="5000" error-channel="errorChannel" > <int:router input-channel="contextStartedEventChannelChannel"
  expression="payload">  
  <int:mapping value="false" channel="errorChannel" />
 </int:router><int:outbound-channel-adapter id="errorChannel"
  ref="errorTracker" method="processError" /> <bean id="errorTracker" class="com.jefferies.fileutility.ErrorTracker" />

Comment: I repeat; there is no way to get the missing directory error in the error channel; it is considered a hard-error and prevents the application from starting. Other errors (runtime) will go to the error channel.

Comment: So how do I handle this (missing directory) error ? How do I handle this hard error ? why its scanning the directory="file:${myapp.incomingFile.path}" even when I have written auto-startup="false"??? Please do help me understand as this is crucial to my project.

Comment: why its even preventing the application from starting when I have mentioned auto-startup="false" ???

Comment: You can't (currently); it's not detected on `endpoint.start()`. It's detected during bean creation (`afterPropertiesSet()`). It's ensuring the bean is properly configured. We can certainly consider deferring this check until later; open an ['Improvement' JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) but, right now, this particular mis-configuration is considered fatal. It's not clear why you want this because you say you want to shut down the application anyway if the directory is not present.

Comment: Gary, so in the current scenario how do I handle this hard error (directory not present). I have to do this. There must surely be some way to do this in spring-integration. I want to log a message in the log file and shutdown gracefully if the directory is not present and NOT print a stacktrace. Please help

Comment: The only way to do that right now is when you create the application context (more specifically, when it is initially refreshed), you would have to put it in a `try` block and catch `BeanCreationException`, looking for the `IllegalArgumentException` cause.